# Connecting to an oracle database in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Hi I use the following code to connect to an orace database in Visual Studio 2008 and it is falling over with the exception of ServerVersion threw an invalid operation exception at line 3:

```
m_strConnectionString = Settings.GetMandatoryConfig("databases", "SourceDB");
m_strQueryTerminator = Settings.GetConfig("databases", "QueryTerminator");
m_odbConn = new OleDbConnection(m_strConnectionString);
m_sql = new SQL(DatabaseType.AnsiSQL, false);
```

m_strConnectionString is a valid TNS names connection string and is as follows:

> Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=myDS;User
>   ID=myID;Password=myPW

This has previously worked and is using an IIS web server to host the application.  I recently converted it from .Net 1.1 (VS 2003) to .Net 3.5/2 (VS 2008) and can't get it working as yet in VS 2008.

Thanks

Comment: Did you verified the installation of oracle ole db provider? Using OleDbConnection is right if you use Provider=MSDAORA in your connect string. Check if all path variables and oracle configuration files are set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using the [OracleConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.aspx) class instead of the generic OleDbConnection.  Doing this may give you more specific error information that what you're receiving now - and could help you find your problem quicker.

See here for more information on the [System.Data.OracleClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.aspx) namespace included with the .Net framework.

Comment: Perhaps that's fine to get started but I recommend picking up the Oracle Data Provider for .NET http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html instead since Microsoft will be deprecating System.Data.OracleClient in .NET 4.0.

Comment: great idea ahmad - i agree :)